# How to group using the long list selector in windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, longlistselector

Requirement:-

***Want to show the contact list with alphabets groups.***

Using Long list selector displays the contacts list. In xaml, we mention the  IsFlatList="false" in long list selector for grouping, but it displays the contacts list without groups like list box.

I herewith attached my code for your comments, please let me know where I did mistake in my code.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <!--Heading for the items(a,b,c,d) -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupItemHeaderTemplate">
        <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="5">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" BorderThickness="2" Width="480" Height="40" Margin="0,0,18,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" FontSize="20" Padding="6" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <!-- Heading For the  list -->

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListHeader">
        <Border Background="#FF049ED6" Height="40">
            <TextBlock Text= "{Binding Key}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--Items to display-->

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ListImage}" Height="100" Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="10,2,0,0" ImageFailed="Image_ImageFailed" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListFullName}" Width="200" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="22" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ListBio}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Foreground="Black" Margin="-200,50,0,0" FontWeight="ExtraLight" FontSize="20" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!--Group Intems Panel to show when click on Items Header-->
     <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="GroupItemsPanel">
        <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemHeight="105" ItemWidth="105"></toolkit:WrapPanel>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<toolkit:LongListSelector x:Name="LongListSelectorListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Content}" 
                          Margin="0,235,5,104" Width="480" Background="Transparent" IsFlatList="True" 
                          DisplayAllGroups="False" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" 
                          GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupItemHeaderTemplate}" 
                          ListHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListHeader}" GroupItemsPanel="{StaticResource GroupItemsPanel}" 
                          SelectionChanged="LongListSelectorListBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

### ViewModel:-

```
    ServiceModel sm = new ServiceModel();
    Content = new ObservableCollection<ListContactsModel>();
    Content1 = new ObservableCollection<ListContactsModel>();
    ServiceConstants.Temp_Response = x;//Save The response temp
    ObservableCollection<ListContactsModel> result = ListContactsModel.extract(x, sm, OutGoingInvitation);
    ObservableCollection<ListContactsModel> result1 = ListContactsModel.extract(x, sm, IncomeInvitation);
    AppGlobalConstants.Temp_Response = result;
    if (!((string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.ProvResErrCode))))
    {
        string errCode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorCode) ? sm.NetErrorCode : sm.ProvResErrCode;
        string errDesc = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sm.NetErrorDesc) ? sm.NetErrorDesc : sm.ProvResErrDesc;
        MessageBox.Show(errCode + "/" + errDesc);
    }else if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        Content.Clear();
        Content1.Clear();
        Content = result;//Outgoing Invitations
        Content1 = result1;//Incoming Invitations
        List<AlphaKeyGroup<ListContactsModel>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<ListContactsModel>.CreateGroups(result,
                                  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                                  (ListContactsModel s) => { return s.ListFullName; },
                                  true);
        Console.WriteLine("Content.Count==>>" + Content.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("DataSource.ElementAt(1).Key==>>" + DataSource.ElementAt(1).Key);
        Console.WriteLine("DataSource.ElementAt(2).Key==>>" + DataSource.ElementAt(2).Key);
```

Regards,
Naresh T

Comment: Please add complete code and Please check MSDN Sample of LongListSelector 

They have done same thing what you are willing to do, Verify your code with the below sample you will found answer.

[How to display data in a grouped list in LongListSelector for Windows Phone 8][1]

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Can you ask your question more clearly

Answer (score 1):

I don't see whole code and I don't know what is ListContactsModel. Is it a collection (inherits from IEnumerable/List/...)? Does it have Items propery? Does it have GetEnumerator methods?

As far as I understand AlphaKeyGroup class was taken from here (*if not, read it first*) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

So maybe you want to bind LongListSelector to some property, that receive data from **DataSource** and has the same type **List<_AlphaKeyGroup<*ListContactsModel*>_>** (not to Content)?

Here is a couple of articles about LongListSelector:

- http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api
- http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios (this one will be great for you)

First of all, follow the instructions.

In general grouping in LLS means, that you have collection of items, that consist of Key/Title/Header/whatever and inner collection of group elements.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply. Now only i change the type of Content. Now it's working.. Thanks for the tips..

Comment: Now i have one more doubt.. Now i can show like

A-
 Apple,

B-
 Banana,

T-
 Tiger,
 

etc..

Now i want two Group header.....


Animals-
  Lion,
  Tiger,
  Dog,

Fruits-
  Apple,
  Orange,

............There is only two groups.
So that i want to group with this two group header.
How to achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a property for Animals and Fruits inside of ListContactsModel?

Comment: I don't have enough information, to say what exactly you should do, I just can try to guess. But I think http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios will help you better. This guys are great. They have a bit other approach than on msdn and I think, it's a bit better.